# How to set number of cars and start/destiation point of cars in veins_inet?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I'm new to veins.
After running `veins_inet` example, it was set 3 as number of cars and two places: destination point and start point where creating new cars and making cars disappear. However, I didn't find where to set number of cars and start/destination point of cars in .ned, .ini or in .cc file. The same question is in `RSUScenarioExample`.
I want to set accident time and number of cars instead of 3 cars in `vein_inet` file and default start and destination place.
Would anybody please tell me how to set these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Number of vehicles as well as starting/destination positions can be set in the file `/veins_inet/examples/veins_inet/square.rou.xml` - the format is defined in [SUMO Documentation](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Definition_of_Vehicles%2C_Vehicle_Types%2C_and_Routes.html).

In short:

- number of cars can be set as value of `number` in `<flow>`
- starting position can be set as value of `departPos` in `<flow>`
- destination position can be set as value of `arrivalPos` in `<flow>`